# Getting value of MooTools datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, mootools

I am using this [MooTools datepicker](http://www.monkeyphysics.com/mootools/script/2/datepicker).

How can I get the current value (either Unix TS or date) from it with JavaScript?

My code is:

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
    new DatePicker('.demo_vista', {
        pickerClass: 'datepicker_vista',
        format: 'm/d/Y',
        allowEmpty: true,
        toggleElements: '.date_toggler'
    });
});
```

I have tried the standard `getElementById('mydatepicker').value` but I get `[object NodeList]` everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different versions of this datepicker. Some output UNIX some not.

**To get the value** from the input field/datepicker, If you have a id for it you can use `$('mydatepicker').value` or `document.id('mydatepicker').value`, or plain javascript like you described. Check if the value you get out $('mydatepicker').value is already UNIX. otherwise you can parse the date.

**If you don't have UNIX timestamp** from the input value you can convert the date to it by using:

```
var unix = new Date(this.value).format('%s');
```

In the options (if you don't get a UNIX timestamp) you can also add `inputOutputFormat: 'U',` to specify UNIX should be the value of the input field (some versions have this as default). This input field is hidden because datepicker creates a clone that is the one you see. But this hidden field is the one in the html markup and so the one with ID.

Check this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8LLQ6/)**, change a date and look at console.

Comment: I have tried `getElementById('mydatepicker').value` but I get [object NodeList] everytime.

Comment: @Adelphia, can you post your html?

Comment: Nermind, it's working now, I have no idea what I did, but ultimately getElementById worked.

Comment: @Adelphia, ok. Happy to hear! Comment again if you find more problems.

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker options:

- format - is a visible date format. Does not affect the actual output
  when your form is submitted
- inputOutputFormat - define how the input value of the original
  datepicker input element is interpreted ( the default value U is a
  Unix-timestamp )
- onSelect - Event hook triggered when a date is selected

  ```
  new DatePicker('.demo_vista', { 
      pickerClass: 'datepicker_vista', 
      format: 'm/d/Y',
      inputOutputFormat: 'm/d/Y',
      allowEmpty: true, 
      toggleElements: '.date_toggler',
      onSelect: function( date ) {
          alert( date );
          alert( $('mydatepicker').value );
      }
  });
  ```

Default output from your form will be a Unix-timestamp unless you define inputOutputFormat option, and that value can be taken with `$('mydatepicker').value` ( is the same as `document.getElementById('mydatepicker').value`  )